# Excel file saves date in unknown format

Tags: php, excel

I am importing some an excel file into PHP, and it is returning a field which in excel is displayed as '00:57:48' but when i look in the excel zip it is displayed as '1.4965277777777779E-2' can someone explain to me which format this is and how i can convert it back to the original.

Thanks

Comment: just format cell in your excel sheet to "text"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel stores date and time values as floating point numbers, based on the number of days that have passed since January 1, 1900.

Whenever you store a single time value (like 00:57:48), it is stored as a float and converted to a proper display format when it is acutally displayed. You can play around with that when you enter a time value into a cell, and then explicitly change the formatting of that cell to a number or vice versa.

What I'm wondering about is that 00:57:48 does not correspond to '1.4965277777777779E-2', so this is a bit strange indeed. Based on the normal calculation logic 00:57:48 should be 4,01388889E-02.

Comment: Thanks Gabor, how can I convert this back across using php?

Comment: I'm not that big of a php expert but what I would do is take the numeric value you have and do some calculations with it:
x: your float value. **Hours**: x * 24: number of hours in your time value (you have to take the integer part). **Minutes**: x * 24 * 60 - hours *60: number of minutes in your time value (again, the integer part only). **Seconds**: x * 24 * 60 * 60 - hours * 60 * 60 - minutes * 60: number of seconds in your time value (integer only).

Comment: @frankastin also possible **hours:** `int(x*24)` (as said by Gabor), **minutes:** `x*1440 mod 60` and **seconds:** `x*86400 mod 60` ;)

Comment: Dirk's way is great as well. Once you have the numbers, you can throw them into an mktime() and you're done.